# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing"

Tags: java, junit

On my Ubuntu, I run an java executable, with error about some package I didn't explicitly use in my code. What might be the solution? Thanks.

```
$ java -cp .:/home/tim/program_files/programming/java/junit-4.11.jar MyTest
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:28)
at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:75)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:128)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runClasses(JUnitCore.java:73)
at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hamcrest.SelfDescribing
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 17 more
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From [Junit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install)

> **Plain-old JAR**
>   Download the following JARs and put them on your test classpath:
>
> `junit.jar`   `hamcrest-core.jar`

Add the [hamcrest](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.hamcrest%7Chamcrest-core%7C1.3%7Cjar) core jar to the class path to resolve the issue.

Comment: works. thanks. I didn't use hamcrest explicitly, why is the error?

Comment: @Tim my guess is that JUnit uses it internally.

Comment: Junit uses hamcrest matchers internally. Check usage [here](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/search?utf8=✓&q=hamcrest)

Comment: The error doesn't say hamcrest-core.jar was not found. so how do you guess I need to add it? Suppose you don't know about the package or junit. and just try to deduce from the error message.

Comment: @Tim I knew there was a dependency beforehand. But say if it is a different project the `NoClassDefFoundError` should point you in the correct direction.

Comment: NoClassDefFoundError may be caused by the package the class is in wasn't found? May it be cause by other reasons?

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` means the class was present during compile time and is absent at Runtime. This usually happens when a runtime dependency is missing.

Comment: But at compile time, I didn't specify the hamcrest library. How could it succeed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62637/discussion-between-ajay-george-and-tim).