# Is linking in Java runtime always done dynamically?

Tags: java

Following on from my previous question: [“Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hamcrest/SelfDescribing”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246668/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-hamcrest-selfdes)

I was wondering why I have to specify the package path again when running a Java application?

Is linking in Java always dynamic and not static?

I am from the C world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The Java Virtual Machine dynamically loads, links and initializes classes and interfaces.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html) - Oracle documentation.

Comment: Is it always so? no static linking?

Comment: As far as I know, it is always dynamically-linked. Because Java compiles to bytecode that is interpreted at runtime by the JVM, I believe static linking in the C/C++ sense would be more or less impossible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. In java you could create a jar compiled completely against an interface, then drop in the implementation by providing it in the classpath.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Java is 'dynamically' linked. This allows the libraries to be distributed, relocated, thinned out if you don't need functionality, etc. The linking is essentially done as needed, not even at start up.

Further, Java supports multiple ClassLoaders if you need to, so some systems, like application servers, are able to have multiple versions of the same classes loaded at the same time.